# Asignar valor a un input type radio seleccionado de un campo de un input text

Tags: php, jquery, formularios

Tengo un formulario en el que hay dos botones de radio. Si se clica el primero de ellos, el valor que voy a pasar a la base de datos es un texto que siempre va a ser igual y que corresponde al `value` del `input type="text" id="fijo"`. Si se clica la segunda opción, el usuario ha de introducir el texto que desee y que forzosamente va a ser variable. Lo que quiero hacer (y no sé cómo) es pasar lo que el usuario escriba en el `textarea id="tcontenidoMod"` al valor del `input type="radio" id="modalidad2"`.

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Muchas gracias.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="modalidadE" id="modalidad1" value="Este texto será siempre el mismo">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="fijo" type="text" id="fijo" class="form-control"  value="Este texto será siempre el mismo" size="60" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="modalidadE" id="modalidad2" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea name="tcontenidoMod" id="tcontenidoMod" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba aquí su texto para Modalidad de Ensayo"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

@x3k against SE behavior.

Cuando hago el insert en la BBDD, no hay problema al pedir que incluya el contenido del textarea. Pero cuando le pido que incluya el contenido del campo text, me da un problema no lo inserta.

He hecho un script en php para insertar, en lugar del '$_POST["modalidadE"]' el contenido de esa variable así:

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST["modalidadE"])){
        $modalidadE= $_POST['modalidadE'];} ?>
<?php
```

Pero sigue sucediendo lo mismo:

- Si el insert corresponde al del campo de texto, falla
- Si corresponde al textarea, funciona bien.

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Entendiendo lo que quieres hacer creo que el planteamiento no es el mas correcto. Creo que el `name="modalidadE"` debería de ir en el input y en el textarea y con los radios solo deberías de habilitar o deshabilitar un campo u otro, así se enviara solo el que este habilitado

Comment: Gracias por responder, Ferran. 
Y, entonces, si asigno a mi textarea el name="modalidadE", ¿cómo habilitaría para pasar este valor al input id=modalidad2?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te he puesto en el comentario yo enviaría el texto en el `input` o en el `textarea` y no en los `radios`.

Los radios los usaría a modo de control para habilitar y deshabilitar ya que los elementos deshabilitados no se envían en los formularios.

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[name='radioMod']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()==1){
      $("#fijo").attr("disabled",true);
      $("#tcontenidoMod").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else{
      $("#tcontenidoMod").attr("disabled",true);
      $("#fijo").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="radioMod" id="modalidad1" value="0" checked>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input name="modalidadE" type="text" id="fijo" class="form-control"  value="Este texto será siempre el mismo" size="60" readonly="readonly">
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="radio" name="radioMod" id="modalidad2" value="1">
     </td>
     <td>
       <textarea name="modalidadE" id="tcontenidoMod" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba aquí su texto para Modalidad de Ensayo" disabled></textarea>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Oh, qué amable eres. 

Lo voy a probar. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Ferran:

El script no deshabilita el disabled del textarea al dar clic en el botón de radio id="modalidad2"

Comment: @MlSaura ¿has cambiado los valores de los `radio`? En mi ejemplo he puesto los valores a `0` y `1`. Ademas también puse `disabled` por defecto en el `textarea` para que la primera vez aparezca deshabilitado. Por cierto, Ferran es el nombre de la persona que edito tu pregunta :)

Comment: Ufff, perdona, x3k against SE behavior. Te agradezco entonces a ti las respuestas a mi pregunta. 

Copié tal cual tanto el script como el form que indicaste. El textarea no deja de estar deshabilitado al clicar sobre el radio id="modalidad2"

Comment: @MlSaura ¿Podrías copiar el código en la pregunta a ver si puedo ver cual es el problema?

Comment: No entiendo. El código es el que tú has indicado en tu respuesta

Comment: Perdón, me confundí. Incluyo todo el código arriba modificando la pregunta.

Comment: Es curioso que tu código hace que se habilite el textarea al clicar el botón de radio 'id="modalidad2"' pero al incluir todos los elementos en las pruebas que yo he hecho (el código forma parte ahora de la pregunta), el textarea permanece bloqueado pese a clicar el segundo botón de radio.

Comment: @MlSaura Lo mas recomendable es poner los `<script>` al final del `DOM` (footer etc) En este caso también ha sido parte fallo mio por no meter el script en `.ready`, actualizo la respuesta. Por si no queda claro, lo que te ocurre es que estas asignando el evento antes de que se cargue el `DOM`

Comment: ¡¡¡Genial!!! Muchísimas gracias por tu amabilidad.

Comment: Una pregunta más: Con tu código habilito o deshabilito los input text junto a los botones de radio correspondientes y les paso el valor "0" o "1". 

Pero en el caso del segundo botón de radio, no quiero escribir 1 en la base de datos sino lo que el usuario escriba en el textarea id="tcontenidoMod". 

¿Cómo hago eso?

Comment: @MlSaura Eso lo envias en el `textarea`. Si en el servidor coges el valor del `name="modalidadE"` si no recuerdo mal en `PHP` sería con `$_POST['modalidadE']` y dependiendo del radio seleccionado llegara el valor "fijo" o el que el usuario ha escrito en el textarea.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionar el problema del insert insertando, en lugar de '$_POST['modalidadE']' una variable. La anteriormente indicada no funcionaba porque no me permitía insertar nada para el primer botón de radio, pero esta otra, funciona perfectamente.

```
<?php
  $modalidadE= "Este texto será siempre el mismo";
  if(isset($_POST['modalidadE']) && $_POST["radioMod"] !== "0"){
  $modalidadE= $_POST['modalidadE'];} 
?>
```

Muchísimas gracias @x3k against SE behavior tu script fue definitivo.